# Javascript global variable

Tags: javascript, variables, global

I have a script tag with 'A' variable and has been initialised as 16 but when I use alert on IE under onclick event, I received undefine rather than 16.

Is this the problem in IE 6?

e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var A =16;
</script>

<a href=""  onclick="javascript:alert(A);">undefine</a>
```

Comment: Would you mind posting a code sample that produces the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd bet on it being caused by some slight confusion...

Being that putting var in front of a variable puts that variable into the local scope only in Javascript, and a variable delcaration without it (a = 16) is global.

```
function test() {
    a = 16;
    var b = 16;

}
test();

alert(a); # alerts 16
alert(b); # throws error, b is undefined
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why exactly this has been down voted.

Comment: Just to add, just looked it up. What I have said is correct, with the exception that if I had var c = 16, and the relevant alert inside test() it would have worked.

Irrespective, it sounds like a scope problem.

Comment: +1 for useful information in trying to answer a rather vague question (don't know why you were voted down either). It could well be a scope issue; it could also be a typo! ;)

Comment: ... but.. yes your answer covers the local/global dif.. that said .. "var A =16;" in OP-s question.. should.. also.. be in a global scope as it is not in a closure? tell me i'm wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a simple concept of global and local variable.. when You run the method the variable which is global has got its value and the variable which is local has also got the value but its lifecycle expires on going out of function thus it throws error to be undefined

Answer (score -1):

You need to post an example of what you are talking about, but the problem may be in where your script tag is and where you are calling the variable from.

Comment: Put comments like this as a comment under the question, not as an answer.

Comment: @Gert G Didn't I give at least half an answer.  :)

Comment: A very vague one. And for the record... I didn't give you a -1.